# Integer initialization of enum outside of range

Tags: c++, enums, c++17

I am reading Bjarne Stroustrup's "Tour of C++" (2:nd edition). In chapter 2.5, he discusses enums with the following example:

```
enum class Color {red,blue,green};
```

In the same chapter, he says that it is allowed to initialize an enum with a value from its underlying type (int by default), and gives the following example:

```
Color x = Color{5}; //OK, but verbose
Color y {6};        //Also OK
```

I tested, and this certainly compiles. However, I am a bit confused about the meaning of initializing an enum with 5 or 6, which falls outside the "range" (0-2) of Color. What are actually the values of x and y in the above example? By testing, it does not appear to be either "red", "green" or "blue".

As a follow-up question, why is this "out-of-range" initialization of enums allowed? It does not seem very sensible.

Note that integer initialization of enums is not supported in C++11, but only in C++17 and forward.

Comment: Enums in C++ are thin wrappers around integers. `enum class` is a bit safer since it won't implicitly cast back and forth, but under the hood it's still an integer with a few named values.

Comment: @Eljay That sounds correct to me. `enum class` defaults to `int` as the underlying type, unlike the plain `enum`.

Comment: It's usually not ideal to initialize an enum outside of its defined values, but not ill-formed.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Ok I see, thanks! Any idea why it is implemented in this way? It does not seem very sensible to initialize the enum outside of the "range".

Comment: @AndyG Is there any good reason to allow initialization outside of the defined values?

Comment: @QuercusRobur: the "why" is a complicated answer, but basically it's to be as close to an unscoped enum as possible to encourage switching them out for better type safety.

Comment: @AndyG Alright, thanks! Just to clarify, by "uncooked enum" do you mean a "plain" enum, i.e. "enum" and not "enum class"?

Comment: Is there a good reason to allow it? Sure, I bet it makes it easier for implementers as well as to allow devs to support their unholy hacks of yore. Is there a good reason for devs to do it? Generally no.

Comment: Uncooked --> unscoped. Yes, an "old" C style enum. Sorry, I'm on mobile.

Comment: Is "what counts as a valid range for conversion from a number to an enum" explicitly one of the differences between scoped and unscoped enums? That is, this sample calling code is valid for `enum class Color` but would be UB for `enum Color`, right?

Comment: @NathanPierson It appears that integer initialization is not allowed for unscoped enums. If I declare enum Color {red,blue,green}; and then Color x {1}; or Color x = 1; I get "invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘main()::Color’".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat • Thank you for the bit of knowledge!  I has *assumed* `enum` and `enum class` both had the same bit-range behavior, if not otherwise specified by a backing store integral type.

Comment: AFAIK, in case if you initialize the enum variable with the integer value not specified in the enum list and then you have `switch(c) { case red: case green: case blue: default:}`, then the `default` section may never be called as you tested all the defined values of the enum (i.e. red, green and blue)

Comment: @DmytroOvdiienko I just tested with `enum Color {red,blue,green};` and `c = 5`. The default case was called in the switch statement.

Comment: Think of it like this: an enum has all the values of the underlying integer type. It's just that some of these values have a name.

Comment: @QuercusRobur:  According to standard: _If the underlying type is not fixed and the source value is out of range, the behavior is undefined_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comes from C: enumerated types are fancy integers. The names of the enumerations are handy, but they don't define every value that the type can represent.

Probably the most common use for an enumerated type is, though, as a simple list of constants:

```
enum state [
    off,
    starting,
    running,
    shutting_down,
    out_of_service
};
```

The values of these enumerators are `off` == 0, `starting` == 1, `running` == 2, `shutting_down` == 3, and `out_of_service` == 4.

But, formally, you aren't restricted to those values. And sometimes there are interesting combinations of values:

```
enum color {
    red   = 0b0001,
    green = 0b0010,
    blue  = 0b0100
};
```

The values of these enumerators have been carefully contrived so that each one uses a different bit; that lets us combine values easily.

For example, the color "purple" is a combination of red and blue. Combining the bits for red (0b0001) and blue (0b0100) gives us a value with two bits set: 0b0101. That's the value 5, and it's not one of the named values. But it's okay to store that value:

```
color x = red | blue;   // x represents the value of purple
std::cout << x << '\n'; // displays 5
```

(I'm not compiling this, since I don't have a compiler on this laptop, so you might need a cast here)

Similarly,

```
color y = red | green;  // y represents the value of yellow
std::cout << y << '\n'; // displays 3
```

The rule for what values can be stored is a bit complicated, but basically, if the bits are there, you can use them.

Doing this obviously lets you store values that represent multiple things, but it also lets you query those things:

```
bool has_blue(color c) { return c & blue; }
assert(has_blue(x));
assert(!has_blue(y));
```

So, basically, this lets you use a named type rather than a generic integer type when you need to store and query numeric fields. Sure, you could do all this with ordinary constants:

```
const int red    = 0b0001;
const int green  = 0b0010;
const int yellow = 0b0100;
```

and combine them as integer values:

```
int x = red | blue;
int y = red | green;
```

but now the type of each of these is just a plain old `int`, not nearly as descriptive as calling it `color`.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a typo in the definition of green and blue, i.e. should it be binary rather than hex?

Comment: @QuercusRobur -- oops. That `0b` prefix is relatively new, and I'm used to writing this kind of constant as hex. In fact, I originally wrote those values as `0x01`, `0x02`, and `0x04`, but changed them to make the bits easier to visualize. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

> why is this allowed

Well, one of the fundamental design goals of C++ (and i will probably get this quote wrong) was that Bjarne "didn't know what problems people needed to solve" and therefore designed the language to allow you to violate its guard rails.

As to when this might be useful, some times you want something to be in a combined state:

```
enum Color 
{ 
    red = 1 << 0, 
    blue = 1 << 1, 
    green = 1 << 2 
};
```

So the valid value of 5 is greater than the highest labeled value of the enum (4), and would represent something both green and red.

Comment: Yep, quite so.  The bit range for that `enum Color` is 0 .. 7 (inclusive).  So 5 is definitely a legit value within that bit range, even though the highest enumerator in that enum is 4.  On the other hand, 8... who knows what will happen.

Comment: @Eljay Chaos, Anarchy. Dogs and cats living together. Made an edit based on your feedback. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I ended up accepting the answer by Pete Becker since it elaborates a bit more on how you can use values outside of the range.